Goerli faucet website showing error":"Invalid chainNetwork


When I tried to visit the Goerlifaucet.com, it showed error.
I don't know how else to get funds for my test account..

Goerli testnet is deprecated. You should use Sepolia testnet instead.
And, to get Sepolia-ETH, you can refer to this post.
